# csv writer escape character issue

Tags: java, csv

My application i want  write csv writer issue in ecapse character

output of following

```
"art_number
 test"  "category"  "testtest"
```

but i want like

```
"art_number\ntest"  "category"  "testtest"
```

Here is my code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    CSVWriter writer = new CSVWriter(new FileWriter("D:/temp/test.csv"), '\t' );

    // int i = 0;
    List<String[]> csvRows = new ArrayList<String[]>();
    String[] header = new String[17];
    header[0] = "art_number\ntest"; 

    header[1] = "category";     
    header[2] = "testtest";
    writer.writeNext(header);

    writer.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically `\n` is treated a **new line character** and you can escape it using `\` as shown below:

```
header[0] = "art_number\\ntest";
```

---

#### EDIT

Just update the values here before writing it into csv file

```
for (int i=0;i<header.length;i++) {
    header[i]=header[i].replaceAll("\\n", "\\\\n");
}

writer.writeNext(header);
```

**Note:** use `List` instead of static array to avoid `NullPointerException` in this case.

Comment: don't change my existing data can u give me another solution

Comment: Great, you don't want to change the data but why?

Comment: share the code of `CSVWriter` class and what is hidden in `writeNext()` method.

Comment: **Try to understand the root cause.**

Comment: because whole data make dynamically it is difficult to handle  that why i ask another solution

Comment: Look at my post again.

Comment: public CSVWriter(Writer writer,
                 char separator,
                 char quotechar,
                 String lineEnd)